# Is there any relationship to light and gravity since both propagate at the same speed in a vacuum?

Tags: gravity, photons

One thing I find interesting is how gravity and light propagate through space at the same speed.

Is this a coincidence or are they some how interconnected in ways that we are trying to research currently ??

Comment: This is a great question and the kind you should always be asking. In my opinion they are definitely related and a theory could be offered that connects them on a particle basis.

Comment: One can try to invoke gravitons to explain the speed of gravity via the fact that it is massless. Anyway, gravity is described by space-time curvature and the electromagnetic field is the curvature of the electromagnetic four-potential. The only concrete link one can see between the two theories is the weak field approximation of gravity, which is called gravitoelectromagnetism.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7041