# Why is the speed of gravity the same as the speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light

Why is speed of gravity the same as the speed of light, can anyone explain in simple terms?

Comment: Don't think of it as the speed of light. Think of it as a maximum speed limit in our universe. Some things just happen to move as fast as possible. That would be light. And that would be gravitational fields. And electromagnetic radiation in general etc. The good question, though, is why these things *do* move as fast as possible.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7041/2451