# speed of gravitational waves

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves

Do gravitational waves have a certain speed? Is it the speed of light or infinite, or am I misunderstanding what a gravitational wave is? I think it is a ripple in spacetime caused by interactions between objects, but i could be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The speed of gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, it is the speed of light.

As to what gravity actually is, oh boy, now ***that's*** a question. Physicists are still trying to work it into the Standard Model.

Comment: I know gravity is a pretty big mistery. Have they confirmed the existence of gravity waves yet, have they detected any?

Comment: @stanleydodds: Gravitational waves were recently discovered last month. Note that they are not fixed at the speed of light $c$, and may propagate slower depending on their amplitude. For a brief overview of gravitational wave metric in GR, see http://perimeterscholars.org/410.html, lecture 4.