# If the sun stopped burning, would we ever know it?

Tags: gravity, sun

I read somewhere that since gravity moves at the speed of light, if the sun were to leave its position we would "know" about it through the absence of light and its gravitational effects on our planet at the same time.  If this is the case, would we ever even know?  Would the effects of its gravity change on our planet kill us all before we realized the light went out?

Thanks

Comment: If the sun stops giving off-light, then that won't affect it's gravity.

Comment: If the sun suddenly stopped burning (i.e. stopped emitting light), we would only know 8 minutes later.

Comment: Do you mean "leave the position" or "burn out"??

Comment: I don't think you understand.  Gravity "moves" at the speed of light.  I am asking if, should the sun move from its position, would everyone on earth die due to the gravity changes at the exact same time that the light stops coming, so that we will never know that it went out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity if it helps clear up all of your confusion.

Comment: Comments containing insulting phrases have been removed. Keep it civil, folks.

Comment: here's similar question that can help you - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-speed-of-gravity

Answer (score 0):

If the sun simply vanished the earth (with moon on tow) would follow Newton and continue in a straight line. Unlikely anyone would notice instantly - the earth's gravity at it's surface vastly exceeds the sun's influence but it would certainly mess up the tides. Sailors would know something is up but not what. It's conceivable that there would be widespread tsunamis depending on the earth's rotation relative to the sun when it went poof and the day's tides relaxed. 
People on the day side would start to panic 8 minutes later when the lights go out, people on the night side would have a few more hours of peace and quiet.

After that, we can look forward to steady cooling. The deep ocean probably won't freeze for millennia but primary production will stop, the food chain will collapse, and everything on the surface will likely expire after a few months. Well stocked survivalists might last a year depending on their fuel reserves. (this is purely guesswork on my part)

Comment: But I think that it would not "follow Newton and continue in a straight line" until the same time that the light stopped reaching us.  Gravity moves at the speed of light, right?

Comment: We don't know. This would be an excellent test, too bad no one will care about the result.