# What is the rate at which the field of an electron spreads?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light

There are 2 steps in the creation of a force field:
(1) first the object comes into existence
(2) then the field appears.
In the case when a photon splits into an electron and an antielectron, these 2 bodies suddenly pop into existence, whose electromagnetic and gravitational fields then come into existence. what is the rate at which they spread?

Comment: It is unclear whether things happen the way you say: in the quantum world it is not possible yet to give a temporal order to the "creation of a particle" and the "appearance of a field". On the other hand, here fields are quantized, so "appearance of a field" would be "appearance of a field particle". So your premises cannot yet be proven. As for your question, both electromagnetic and gravitational fields propagate at the speed of light.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/2451 and links therein.