# What is the speed of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light, relativity, faster-than-light

Hypothetically, let`s say that one day our Sun is suddenly removed from the galaxy. For us, on earth, would take up to 8.3 minutes to notice that the sun was removed, since the distance from the earth and the sun is approximately 8.3 light-minutes.

However, what about gravity? Would we feel immediately here on earth?  Could we say then that, if *gravitons* really exist, they travel faster than the *photons*?

Comment: Your hypothetical is inconsistent with the best theory of gravity we have.  Regardless, according to that theory, gravitational disturbances propagate at the invariant speed $c$.

Comment: Duplicate of [The speed of gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/)