# Relic graviton background: how to observe it?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

Question dedicated to the memory of Steven Weinberg, whose books I read as a child and undergraduated student!

Beyond using gravitational waves, are out there any other ideas or proposals to detect the relic graviton background with $T\leq 0.9K$?

Comment: Why are you excluding gravitational waves?

Comment: I am not excluding them, I only want to know if there are alternative probes to relic gravitons BEYOND gravitational waves...

Comment: So you want to know if there probes for gravitational waves other than gravitational waves?

Comment: As I mentioned [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/490079/123208), we may *never* have the technology to detect single gravitons.

Comment: So are you think about things like detecting the GW background using polarization of the CMB (like BICEP2 originally claimed)?