# What does it mean be gravity propagates with $c$?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, causality, locality

I know that gravity propagates with speed of light. Does it mean that if Earth's orbit will disturb after 2 years if a supermassive black hole suddenly appears 2 light years away? Is this related to gravitons which will transmit gravity by travelling at speed of light?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How fast does gravity propagate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5456/)

Comment: Yes, if a large object suddenly comes into existence 2 light-years away, then we won't feel the gravitational effect until after 2 years. Rather than thinking of the value of $c$ as "the speed of light", I find it fruitful to simply think of it as "the maximum speed limit for anything". And some things happen to move at this maximum speed, for example light in vacuum (electromagnetic propagation) and gravitational propagation.

Comment: @Steeven:What if that object/event at 2 LY is similar to big bang? Will that still be 2 years?

Comment: For all things we know of, that is how it will work. $c$ is an upper speed limit for anything in this world. How exactly a new Big Bang would unfold is not a question many can answer...