# Is it possible for a black hole singularity to interact gravitationally with other celestial bodies (if we analyze it using the concept of gravitons)?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality, singularities

It is known to all that the travelling speed of gravitons (the propagation speed of gravitational field) is not instant. So for black holes, the gravitons (the gravitational field) generated by the singularity of the black holes needs time to travel before exerting gravitational pulling forces on other celestial bodies. But,according to gravitational time dilation, the time near black holes are extremely dilated to infinity. This indicates, given the limited age of the universe, the gravitons (gravitational field) generated by the singularity of any black holes have NOT exert any pulling forces on any celestial bodies yet. Thus, we can conclude, it is impossible for any current celestial body to be pulled by the gravity of any black hole and orbit around a black hole. And, actually there should be no celestial bodies now gravitationally pulled by any black holes at all. But, this conclusion is apparently absurd. Any friends can explain this please?
Some friend tried to explain it by saying that gravitons already existed before the black hole is formed, this is apparently not a relevant answer because the gravitons generated before the formation of the black hole already propagated away to far away in the deep space, so if there is no new gravitons generated by the black hole after the black hole is formed, nearby celestial bodies will not gravitationally interact with the black hole.

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745878

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3204 "Therefore, rather than gravity having a special property that enables it to cross the horizon, in a certain sense gravity can't cross the horizon, and it is that very property that forces gravity outside of it to remain the same." Also see my answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696441/123208

Comment: Your logic is correct, but it is based on a wrong premise. The source of gravity in a black hole is not the singularity, but the horizon. The singularity has nothing to do with gravity, does not attract anything, and does not “emit gravitons”. The singularity is not an object in space, but a moment of time in the future that cannot affect us today in any way at all.